# RaspberryPi Cross-GCC, bluetooth lib missing

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi3

I am using Eclipse IDE and prebuild tool chain from https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools , compiler is arm-linux-gnueabihf for Raspberry Pi 3.
I am trying to linked the bluetooth lib in project (-lbluetooth). 
However, I am get below error

`/.../linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld can not find -lbluetooth.`

Please let me how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're compiling for a specific Linux distro you should probably take the library from that distro. (Assuming the file isn't provided that is, rather than it is but you're just not finding it in your link step.) Or are you compiling for bare metal instead?

Comment: RaspberryPi having Linux rasppberrypi 4.14.62-v7+ .. arm71. so how to link these libs from distro to eclipse project